# Integrating GA in chrome extension, manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I need to integrate GA into my chrome extension, using manifest v3. it looks like I miss something, but I can't figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

My extension has only a content script and background.js where I'm listening on events, to execute content.js when the user clicks on the Icon, in the extension toolbar. Content script by himself injects widget UI into websites, where users can interact with. And I need to track click events.

And in terms of manifest v3 [enter link description here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#content-security-policy), I need to use protect GA scripts like

```
    "content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"
    },
```

But when I try to refresh my extension on chrome://extansions page, it throwing me a popup with a failed status
[image]

Maybe someone has any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by embedding the `analytics.js` file into my extension.

Then the `ga` function would be availabe in the window scope `window.ga` on the content scripts.

Comment: Could you please explain how you would do it with google tag manager? Maybe you can provide it as an anwser to that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981213/why-does-the-chrome-extension-not-trigger-google-analytics-googletagmanager?noredirect=1#comment121916885_68981213

Comment: Does that really work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the analytics embedding documentation and request a script at "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js ". But according to this [document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_analytics/), for extensions you should use the following version: "https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js". (and update manifest accordingly)

In the given document you can find more detailed information on the implementation of Google analytics in the extension:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_analytics/

Important clarification:
Even if you correct everything according to this official documentation, you will probably get a manifest filling error. I have not found a solution to this problem and, in general, it seems that it is impossible to connect Google analytics to the extension with version 3 of the manifest (this is inaccurate)

Comment: This documentation that you're reffering to is not accurate as it is not possible to load external scripts in v3 extenstions. I'm wondering since both GA and Google Chrome extenstions are Google products there must be a way to use Google Analytics with v3 extenstions.