# Why does the Chrome Extension not trigger Google Analytics / GoogleTagManager?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to add Google Analytics / Google Tag Manager into my Chrome Extension. I got the following snippet:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=X-XXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'X-XXXXXXXXX);
</script>
```

When I add this snippet into a random HTML (not Chrome Extension) I see two request in DevTools:

1. https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?...
2. https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?

This is correct, this works. I see logs in the Google Dashboard.

But when I add the same snippet in the popup.html of my Chrome Extension, open DevTools and refresh the page I only see the first request in DevTools. No warnings, no errors and no Logs in the Google Dashboard.

Manifest V3

```
 "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem https://ssl.google-analytics.com chrome-extension://* 'unsafe-inline' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com"
  },
```

Any idea why there is only the first request in the Chrome Extension?

Comment: You can't use external scripts in ManifestV3, see also https://crbug.com/1164452.